# How do the Tamron and Sigma 70-200mm F2.8 lenses compare for photographing high school sports?

Tags: sigma, tamron, lens-recommendation, sports

I want to get a lens I can use for indoor high school wrestling and football. With my budget I’m between these two. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

- Tamron SP 70-200mm F/2.8 Di VC USD For Canon or
- Sigma 70-200mm F2.8 EX DG OS HSM Lens for Canon

Comment: Do you have the option of renting either? What features have you most concerned/confused? Which are you leaning toward and why?

Comment: I just would like to know what brand is more preferred?

Comment: Responding to your answer/comment - lenses are so varied across even a single brand that one cannot really compare brands (with some exceptions, as always). Tamron and Sigma both have fantastic lenses in their lineup and not-so-good lenses as well. The brand should have little impact on your decision. So, I restate: What features have you most concerned/confused? Which are you leaning toward and why?

Comment: Bryan Carnathan's [review of the Sigma 70-200mm F2.8 EX DG OS HSM](https://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Sigma-70-200mm-f-2.8-DG-OS-HSM-Lens-Review.aspx) includes numerous comparisons to both the Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II and the Tamron SP 70-200mm F/2.8 Di VC USD. In terms of pure image quality, the Tamron lens he tested was a little better than the Sigma lens he tested. That seems to be the general consensus I've seen from many reviewers. Other factors may be equally or more important to you, though.

Comment: You can [compare test images](https://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=806&Camera=453&Sample=0&FLI=4&API=2&LensComp=1116&CameraComp=453&SampleComp=0&FLIComp=3&APIComp=2).

Answer (score 2):

I'd used a Sigma 70-200 f2.8 for Nikon in the past (I think around 2013). I'm not sure if it's the same model as you described, but I can say that it was quite nice. I used it to photograph a nighttime football ("soccer") game and had no issues at all.

I can tell you that when I later got the actual Nikon 70-200, its biggest boon was its autofocus speed as compared with the Sigma's. But in terms of image quality, etc. the Sigma I'd used was perfectly adequate (for portraits as well) and I'd continue to trust Sigma as a brand.

(They do make the famous 'Bigma' after all!)